# Explaining what a symbol $W^{\vee}$ means

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds

I've found here http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts.html a very interesting paper on Stokes theorem for manifolds with corners. So I've decided to read a paper on manifolds with corners which is also available there: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/corners.pdf

But the first papagraph turned out to be very problematic because of the notation. I've tried browsing previous articles but nothing like that came up.

Here is what bothers me:

Let $W$ be an $m$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, $m \ge  1$. For $ 1 \le  k \le m$ a $k$-sector in $W$ is a non-empty subset of the form $$ \Sigma = \{w \in W | `l_1(w) \ge  c_1, . . . , l_k(w) \ge c_k\}$$
with $c_1, . . . , c_k \in \mathbb{ R}$ and linearly independent $l_1, . . . , `l_k \in W^{\vee}$.

A $0$-sector is $ \Sigma = W$. A sector $ \Sigma \subset  W$ is a $k$-sector for some $k$. If $w \in W$ is a point, then the translation $w +  \Sigma $ also a
$k$-sector: we use the same $i$’s but replace $c_i$ with $c_i + `l_i(w)$.

Could you tell me what $W^{\vee}$ can mean here?

I would also be very grateful to you, if you could explain to me what a $k$-sector is.

Comment: $W^\vee$ denotes the dual vector space of $W$. It is one of the standard-ish notations besides $W^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the [dual space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $W$. Another notation is $W^\ast$.

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense :) Could you give me some intuition about $k-$sector? What is it? How does it work?

Comment: The set is denoted by $\Sigma$ - there is no indication that it is dependent on $c_1, ... \in \mathbb{R}$ or $l_1,... \in W^*$